# Why does postgres scan all the table?

Tags: postgresql

I discovered that a query I am doing on indexed column results in a sequential scan:

```
mydatabase=> explain analyze SELECT account_id,num_tokens,tok_holdings FROM tokacct WHERE address='00000000000000000';
                                            QUERY PLAN                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on tokacct  (cost=0.00..6.69 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (address = '00000000000000000'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 225
 Planning time: 0.108 ms
 Execution time: 0.075 ms
(5 rows)

mydatabase=>
```

However a `\di` shows I have a unique index:

```
mydatabase=> \di
                         List of relations
 Schema |          Name           | Type  | Owner  |     Table      
--------+-------------------------+-------+--------+----------------
......
 public | tokacct_address_key     | index | mydb   | tokacct
.....
```

My table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tokacct (
        tx_id                           BIGINT                  NOT NULL,
        account_id                      SERIAL                  PRIMARY KEY,
        state_acct_id                   INT                     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,        
        num_tokens                      INT                     DEFAULT 0,
        ts_created                      INT                     DEFAULT 0,
        block_created           INT                             DEFAULT 0,
        address                         TEXT                    NOT NULL UNIQUE
        tok_holdings                    TEXT                    DEFAULT ''                      
);
```

As you can see, the `address` field is declared as `UNIQUE`. The `\di` also confirms there is an index. So, why does it use a sequential scan on the table ?

```
Seq Scan on tokacct  (cost=0.00..6.69 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
```

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: @IMSoP 225 rows

Comment: For 226 rows, it's faster to scan the table than lookup the index

Comment: You can try (don't use this in production) to force using the index, by setting "enable_seqscan" to "off", and rerun the EXPLAIN. You should see that the query with  the index is more expensive to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create one page table:

```
db=# create table small as select g, chr(g) from generate_series(1,200) g;
SELECT 200
db=# create index small_i on small(g);
CREATE INDEX
db=# analyze small;
ANALYZE
```

seq scan:

```
db=# explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select g from small where g = 200;
                                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.small  (cost=0.00..3.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.044..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: g
   Filter: (small.g = 200)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 199
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning time: 1.360 ms
 Execution time: 0.066 ms
(7 rows)
```

create three page table:

```
db=# drop table small;
DROP TABLE
db=# create table small as select g, chr(g) from generate_series(1,500) g;
SELECT 500
db=# create index small_i on small(g);
CREATE INDEX
db=# analyze small;
ANALYZE
db=# explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select g from small where g = 200;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using small_i on public.small  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=3.194..3.195 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: g
   Index Cond: (small.g = 200)
   Heap Fetches: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
 Planning time: 0.271 ms
 Execution time: 3.747 ms
(7 rows)
```

now the table takes three pages and index - two, thus index is cheaper...

how do I know the number of pages? it says so in the (verbose) execution plan. And the table?

```
db=# select max(ctid) from small;
  max
--------
 (2,48)
(1 row)
```

Here **2,** means page two (counts from zero).

or again from the verbose plan:

```
db=# set enable_indexonlyscan to off;
SET
db=# set enable_indexscan to off;
SET    
db=# set enable_bitmapscan to off;
SET
db=# explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select g from small where g = 200;
                                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.small  (cost=0.00..9.25 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.124..0.303 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: g
   Filter: (small.g = 200)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 499
   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning time: 0.105 ms
 Execution time: 0.327 ms
(7 rows)
```

Here, **hit=3**